# Host react app and laravel backend(Admin panel) in same laravel application project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5

I want to host the react app and laravel app in the same laravel application project.
The front end app is react and backend(admin panel) laravel.

I want redirect all request to specific front end view except first URL segment == backend/:any

Eg.

http://host.com/backend/(any)
Continue with laravel router

http://host.com/(any) except backend/
Continue with react router

Any idea for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here, either pass a regular expression to the `any` route to ignore API prefixed routes

```php
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
   return view('index.blade.php');
})->where('any', '^(?!backend).*$');
```

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('index.blade.php');
});
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#fallback-routes)

#### Fallback Routes

Using the `Route::fallback` method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request. Typically, unhandled requests will automatically render a "404" page via your application's exception handler. However, since you may define the `fallback` route within your `routes/web.php` file, all middleware in the `web` middleware group will apply to the route. You are free to add additional middleware to this route as needed:

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

> The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application.

Comment: What if he had multiple admin routes? In that case if we will enter for example "/backend/users", it will not know in which view actually to return.

Comment: Thanks, @CaddyDZ, fallback method is the ideal one for my problem

Comment: I faced this challenge today. Here's what I did:
I moved my Lavarel public directory to a sub-folder.
Then, I copied the content of React build folder to the root of my server's public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the "routes/web.php":

```php
// WRITE BACK-END ROUTES AT FIRST
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'backend',
], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('admin-page-1', 'AdminController@page1')->name('page1');
    Route::get('admin-page-2', 'AdminController@page2')->name('page2');
    // some other admin routes if you need
});
// FRONT ROUTE(S)
Route::get('/{text}', 'FrontController@front')->name('front');
```